# How to integrate byobu (tmux) and vim split switching?

Tags: command-line, byobu, tmux

In byobu you can move between splits with the <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>ARROW</kbd> key combination.

I found this guide on making Vim work with tmux; but, I'm wondering how I can make it work with byobu key bindings or if it is even possible.

https://robots.thoughtbot.com/seamlessly-navigate-vim-and-tmux-splits

It uses a vim plugin and this `~/.tmux.conf`:

```
bind -n C-h run "(tmux display-message -p '#{pane_current_command}' | grep -iq vim && tmux send-keys C-h) || tmux select-pane -L"
bind -n C-j run "(tmux display-message -p '#{pane_current_command}' | grep -iq vim && tmux send-keys C-j) || tmux select-pane -D"
bind -n C-k run "(tmux display-message -p '#{pane_current_command}' | grep -iq vim && tmux send-keys C-k) || tmux select-pane -U"
bind -n C-l run "(tmux display-message -p '#{pane_current_command}' | grep -iq vim && tmux send-keys C-l) || tmux select-pane -R"
bind -n C-\ run "(tmux display-message -p '#{pane_current_command}' | grep -iq vim && tmux send-keys 'C-\\') || tmux select-pane -l"
```